# What causes the width calculated in px is different in internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm using class to set the width of my `<td class="FormField"></td>` such as:

```
.FormField
{
    width:120pt;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

But the problem is when in internet explorer the calculated width is `width: 324.01px;` while in chrome it is `width: 160px;` which i think is acceptable. How can i solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why don't you use `px` unit ?

Comment: @makonnendossantos this is a class that i need to use to follow the standard. I cannot force a new one or override the existing one. Any suggestion?